# outputting large matrix in python from a dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, matrix, gephi

I have a python dictionary formatted in the following way:

```
data[author1][author2] = 1
```

This dictionary contains an entry for every possible author pair (all pairs of 8500 authors), and I need to output a matrix that looks like this for all author pairs:

```
        "auth1" "auth2" "auth3" "auth4" ...
"auth1"    0       1       0       3
"auth2"    1       0       2       0
"auth3"    0       2       0       1       
"auth4"    3       0       1       0
...
```

I have tried the following method:

```
x = numpy.array([[data[author1][author2] for author2 in sorted(data[author1])] for author1 in sorted(data)])
print x
outf.write(x)
```

However, printing this leaves me with this:

```
[[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 ..., 
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]]
```

and the output file is just a blank text file.  I am trying to format the output in a way to read into Gephi (https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/csv-format/)

Comment: Does you original dictionary include zero values too? or only non-zero values? If you could show the exact format of your original dictionary it would be nice.

Comment: how big is this? I.e. how many authors? The representation may depend on this ...

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it right, your list comprehension is inverted. This will give you the expected result:

```
d = dict(auth1=dict(auth1=0, auth2=1, auth3=0, auth4=3),
         auth2=dict(auth1=1, auth2=0, auth3=2, auth4=0),
         auth3=dict(auth1=0, auth2=2, auth3=0, auth4=1),
         auth4=dict(auth1=3, auth2=0, auth3=1, auth4=0))

np.array([[d[i][j] for i in sorted(d.keys())] for j in sorted(d[k].keys())])
#array([[0, 1, 0, 3],
#       [1, 0, 2, 0],
#       [0, 2, 0, 1],
#       [3, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pandas`. Using @Saullo Castro input:

```
import pandas as pd        
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Result:

```
>>> df
       auth1  auth2  auth3  auth4
auth1      0      1      0      3
auth2      1      0      2      0
auth3      0      2      0      1
auth4      3      0      1      0
```

And if you want to save you can just do `df.to_csv(file_name)`